# Merge Objects within array based on primary id and sub id

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to push data into an array with a primary Id and then group the sub options based off the primary id and sub id. However, when I console.log arrayExample, the objects aren't mergin based off Primary_id and sub_id

```
const listOfPrimaryId = [{ primary_id: '1234' }, { primary_id: '2345' }, { primary_id: '3456' }]

const arrayNumberOne = [{ main_id: '1234', sub_id: 'htx', indv_ids: 'bf' }, { main_id: '2345', sub_id: 'htx', indv_ids: 'gg' }, { main_id: '3456', sub_id: 'sam', indv_ids: 'bg' }, { main_id: '3456', sub_id: 'sam', indv_ids: 'hh' }, { main_id: '1234', sub_id: 'kev', indv_ids: 'app' }]

const arrayExample = []

for (let j = 0; j < listOfPrimaryId.length; j++) {
    let diffPrimaryId = listOfPrimaryId[j]['primary_id']

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayNumberOne.length; i++) {
        let primaryId = arrayNumberOne[i]['main_id'];
        let subId = arrayNumberOne[i]['sub_id'];
        let iDOptions = arrayNumberOne[i]['indv_ids']

        if (primaryId == diffPrimaryId) {

            type InnerFish = {
                sub_id: string;
                id_opt: string[];
            }

            type MainFish = {
                primary_id: string;
                package: InnerFish
            }

            let sampleData2: InnerFish = {
                sub_id: subId,
                id_opt: [iDOptions]
            }

            let sampleData: MainFish = {
                primary_id: primaryId,
                package: sampleData2
            }

            arrayExample.push(sampleData)
        }
    }
}
```

After the above is performed, I have the below output from arrayExample.

```
[
  { primary_id: '1234', package: { sub_id: 'htx', id_opt: ['bf'] } },
  { primary_id: '1234', package: { sub_id: 'kev', id_opt: ['app'] } },
  { primary_id: '2345', package: { sub_id: 'htx', id_opt: ['gg'] } },
  { primary_id: '3456', package: { sub_id: 'sam', id_opt: ['bg'] } },
  { primary_id: '3456', package: { sub_id: 'sam', id_opt: ['hh'] } }
]
```

arrayExample doens't combine the primary_id or sub_id. I'm trying to build the data to be similar to the below output.

```
[
       { primary_id: '1234', package: [ { sub_id: 'htx', id_opt: ['bf'] }, { sub_id: 'kev', id_opt: ['app'] } ] },
       { primary_id: '2345', package: [ { sub_id: 'htx', id_opt: ['gg'] } ] },
       { primary_id: '3456', package: [ { sub_id: 'sam', id_opt: ['bg', 'hh'] } ] },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually merging the array in your example.  This might be a better solution.

```
type InnerItem = { main_id: string, sub_id: string, indv_ids: string };

const arrayExample = listOfPrimaryId.map((primaryItem:{ primary_id: string }) => {
  const package: {sub_id: string, id_opt: string[]} = [];

  arrayNumberOne.forEach((innerItem: InnerItem ) => {
    if(innerItem.main_id === primaryItem.primary_id){
       // check if we added sub item to package array already
      const existingIndex = package.findIndex((val)=> val.sub_id === innerItem.sub_id);
      if(existingIndex >= 0) // if we have
        package[existingIndex].id_opt.push(innerItem.indv_ids)
      else // if not add it
        package.push( {sub_id: innerItem.sub_id, id_opt: [innerItem. indv_ids]}
    }  
  });
  return { primary_id: primaryItem.primary_id, package};
});
```

You can change up the typing declarations.

Comment: This worked! I did have to make some changes and minor adjustments, but ultimately got me what i needed!